# SQL query doesn't get inserted

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've been trying to get my query to work for some time it runs but doesn't insert anything nor does it return any errors.

The database connection is open and is successfuly connection.

The Table is called errorlog and holds the following data

```
- id (int autoincremental, Primary key, Unique)
- exception (varchar)
- time (DateTime)

exception = String(error message)
time = DateTime.Now
```

Here's the code:

```
 public void insertError(string error, DateTime time)
    {
        SqlCeParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlCeParameter[]  
        {  
           new SqlCeParameter("@exception", error), 
           new SqlCeParameter("@time", time)
        };

        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO errorlog (exception, time) VALUES(@exception, @time)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Removed quotes around @exception

Heres the connection:

```
protected DataController()
    {
        try
        {
            string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DataController)).CodeBase).Replace(@"file:\", "") + @"\";
            string strCon = @"Data Source = " + appPath + @"Data\EasyShop.sdf";
            connection = new SqlCeConnection(strCon);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        connection.Open();
    }
```

Finally the way it gets called:

```
public bool log(string msg, bool timestamp = true)
    {
        DataController dc = DataController.Instance();
        dc.insertError(msg, DateTime.Today);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: time = DateTime, I've tried it with ToString() also setting the DataType to nVarChar. Not difference at all. Nothing gets inserted without any errors.

Comment: Remove the quotes in @exception and try again.

Comment: Refactor your code for starters.. the whole approach looks to be wrong especially in how you are handling the parameters

Comment: Removed them doesn't change anything.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Also tried it the regular (sql injection sensitive way) didn't work either. It's strange that I don't receive any errors at all.

Comment: you need to wrap your code around a Try{}Catch{} also where are you opening the Connection..?

Comment: My code is wrapped in try catch, check my new edit.
I'm catching my exception which return nothing is successfuly completed the try without errors.

Comment: you need to post the code in a more readable fashion so that one can follow your flow.. It doesn't appear that your code is wrapped in a try catch.. also when adding SQL Parameters you don't need add range.. you should look into Parameters.AddWithValue(yourParam, yourValue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Debug your application and see if `connection` points exactly to the
   database you want. Also check if you look for the inserted records
   in the same database.
2. If your `connection` belongs to the transaction, check if it's committed. You will not see those records inserted until transaction is committed.
3. It seems to me, that you `INSERT` is wrong. Remove quotes around `@exception`
4. Open SQL Server Profiler, connect to your database and check if your `INSERT` appears in there.

Comment: - The connection is right one.
    - It's querying to the right connection aswell and with debugging it passes without any error. Also catching Sql based errors.
    - The @exception doesn't work without Quotes either (no errors)

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, i'm not familiar with the formatting here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Maybe it passes without error, but writes records to the database different than the database in which you look for the inserted records. It happened to me at work, where we have different copies of the logically the same database, just used for different purposes.

Comment: I was being a fool all the time, it seemed to writing to an older DataBase file as you were telling me, Thanks for the help and Answered ;)

Comment: Told you so :) It happened to me too.